# Rails: return empty class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have Person that has_many Houses through Addresses. And one of these addreeses of Person is "permanent" (it's where the person lives). So, in Address model, I have following:

```
def self.permanent
  first(:conditions => 'address_type = "permanent"')
end
```

So in my view, I can do:

```
@person.address.permanent.house.id
```

But, when Person has no permanent address, I (of course) get:

```
undefined method `house' for nil:NilClass
```

How should I modify "permanent" method so it will work "transparently" even for people without permanent address? So it will eg. return empty Address class or something.

Comment: I suppose you should move this logic into view and  render different information if permanent address is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Law of Demeter! Or at least the strongly-worded suggestion.

Particularly in cases like this, I'll put a method on Person, like permanent_address, that encapsulates the logic for checking the emptiness, and do any special processing necessary.

An empty address wouldn't help in this case, since you're digging ("Demetering") down into the house as well, so you'd need to decide what to do: add a house, do a conditional check, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looking at the Law of Demeter on Wikipedia, I have one more question: is there a way to create in Person model: has_one :permanent_house :through => :addresses with the condition, that address.address_type="permanent"? And wouldn't it deny the LoD?

Comment: @PetrCezar I believe you could, yes. It would solve the first part of the problem, but you'd still need to deal with the `house.id` part.

Comment: Law of Demeter was originally conceived for C++; it is not particularly useful in Ruby because of Ruby's entirely different object semantics. Don't worry about breaking it if it otherwise seems like the right thing to do.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Could not disagree more: Demeter is language-neutral.

Comment: No, it really isn't. It presupposes a particular type of object semantics -- the "software engineering" type in C++ and Java -- and is more of a hindrance than a help in message-passing languages like Ruby. It also presupposes the tools that the Demeter project created.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Could not disagree more. Whether it's message passing or not, you run in to the exact same problems, as explicitly shown here. How you *handle* the problem can change, the problem remains.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser And I also explicitly stated it's a "strongly-worded suggestion"--it can be taken too far. But the notion that it doesn't matter because it's Ruby is... baffling.

Comment: Disagree if you like, but you're wrong. :) There are definitely reasons to create a `permanent_address` method here, but those have more to do with exposing a decent data model than shying away from method chains. There are ways to deal with the nil-safety issues: I've occasionally used a Smalltalk-style nil that just returns itself instead of `NoMethodError`. Even without doing that, I find that the extra delegated methods that Demeter encourages are extra work and expose things in places where they properly don't belong. Conclusion: LoD is not worth it in Ruby. Why don't you agree?

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Because you're wrong. And antagonistic, something I choose not to participate in.

Comment: About the Ruby issue: LoD ensures that you don't make any assumptions about the type of an object that comes from another class's method. That makes a lot of sense in C++, where it's easy to make critical type errors, and if I were programming in C++, I'd observe LoD strictly. But Ruby's message passing means that the language is more forgiving: you don't normally care about object *types*, just what *messages* objects respond to. This is a good thing. To artificially restrict it because of a software engineering principle derived from a completely different type of language makes no sense.

Comment: I'm not meaning to be antagonistic. I do hold my view pretty strongly, but I genuinely want to hear your reasoning.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser It doesn't make any difference what the type is. The point is to not make assumptions about the "structure or properties of anything else", including what messages an object may respond to. Long chains make an assumption about what messages will be responded to, and what the returns from those messages will respond to, down the line. Carry on.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser [It's not just about counting dots.](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx) The reason I say it's a strongly-worded suggestion instead of a law is precisely because *it depends*.

Comment: Interesting blog post. I do tend to follow "weak LoD" in Ruby, but I get there in a different way. I absolutely agree that coupling too closely to other classes is a bad thing whatever the language, but when dealing with nested value objects (as here) or literate interfaces, I don't tend to worry too much about method chaining (unless it really looks like the semantics of a method are telling me it wants to be delegated). I agree that most of the goals of LoD are worthwhile, but it kind of upsets me when LoD is used as a reason *in itself* for something in Ruby. That's what I was getting at.